# How to sort list of strings where first comes strings with startWith then endWith

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have list of Strings 
for example

```
**united**abc
**united**abcd
abcd**united**
**united**abcde
asdasdad**united**
**united**a
```

it is sorted based on length of the strings, but my idea is to sort like

```
**united**a 
**united**abc
**united**abcd
**united**abcde
abcd**united**
asdasdad**united**
```

so first comes strings where start with united and then others words ending with united. but I still need to keep the length order as well.

I tried this but this doesn't work

```
 if (o1.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
    return@Comparator  -1
  } else if (o2.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
    return@Comparator  1
  } else {
    return@Comparator 0
  }
```

Comment: You need 2 comparators for readabilty. One accesses the other. You also need to think of cases where both o1 and o2 contain the united

Answer (score 3):

It will be a lot more legible and thus less error-prone to combine comparator conditions using the `Comparator.comparing` and `thenComparing` methods:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing((String str) -> !str.startsWith(query))
        .thenComparing(str -> !str.endsWith(query))
        .thenComparingInt(String::length)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

The reason for the `!` symbol is so that our trues will sort before falses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your comparer is that it violates constraints when both inputs either start or end in `query` string. For example, when both `o1` and `o2`'s `name` start in `"united"`, your comparer would return `-1` both for `o1.compareTo(o2)` and its opposite `o2.compareTo(o1)`, which is inconsistent, and therefore throws off the sorting algorithm.

You need to modify the code to check both sides for `startsWith` and `endsWith` before you proceed further:

```
String n1 = o1.name.toLowerCase();
String n2 = o2.name.toLowerCase();
// Both startsWith / both endsWith
if ((n1.startsWith(query) && n2.startsWith(query))
||  (n1.endsWith(query) && n2.endsWith(query))) {
    return Integer.compare(n1.length(), n2.length());
}
// Only one startsWith
if (n1.startsWith(query)) {
    return -1;
}
if (n2.startsWith(query)) {
    return 1;
}
// only one endsWith
if (n1.endsWith(query)) {
    return 1;
}
if (n2.endsWith(query)) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants secondary sorting based on length, so instead of `n1.compareTo(n2)` use `n2.length() - n1.length()`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Right, I missed that part completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 comparators for readabilty.
One to find out if united is in the front and then order by that.
One to find out if united is in the back and then order by that.
One to find order if united isn't contained, or both have the same united priority eg. o1.unitedFront && o2.unitedFront or o1.unitedEnd && o2.unitedEnd.

You are currently not thinking about cases where both strings contain united, because you assume that if the first does, then other doesn't.